# Change color of chart bars based on mouse press event

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, bar-chart, colorbar

I am trying to create an interactive bar chart where the bars of the chart change color when the user selects a value (based on mouse click).  The selected value displays at the bottom of the chart and the bars are supposed to change color dependent on the probability of the selected value being above or below the mean of the a sample.

I am stuck on the coloring of the bars.  When I click on the chart only the first bar changes colors and then does not update with subsequent clicks.

Overall expected result is to allow multiple values to be selected based on mouse click events.  Intention is then to draw the horizontal line at the selected value and then recolor the bars based on the probability of the selected value being within the range of the sample mean. This is being run in jupyter.

I am still new to this so certainly appreciate any advice that you may have.

````
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as wdg
from matplotlib.cm import ScalarMappable

%matplotlib notebook

###Set up dummy data
np.random.seed(12345)
df = pd.DataFrame([np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43000,100000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(43500,140000,3650), 
                   np.random.normal(48000,70000,3650)], 
                  index=[1992,1993,1994,1995])

###Calculate statistics incl confidence interval for the mean.  Calculate 97.5% interquantile range of the normal distribution (being 1.96 x standard error)
df =  df.T
stats = df.describe(percentiles = [0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975])
mean = stats.loc['mean']
onesd_meanerror = df.sem(axis = 0)
error_low = onesd_meanerror*1.96
error_high = onesd_meanerror*1.96

###Setup initial chart and plot bar chart
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x_axis_label = df.columns.values
plt.xticks(x_axis_label)

bars = (ax.bar(x_axis_label, mean, width=0.85, alpha=0.9, align='center',
                yerr = (error_low, error_high), error_kw={'capsize': 10, 'elinewidth': 2, 'alpha':1}))

###Create and display textarea widget
txt = wdg.Textarea(
    value='',
    placeholder='',
    description='Y Value:',
    disabled=False)
display(txt)

### Formats color bar.  Need the scalar mapable to enable use of the color bar.
my_cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('coolwarm')
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=my_cmap, norm=plt.Normalize(0,1))
sm.set_array([])
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm)
cbar.set_label('Probability', rotation=270,labelpad=25)

ydataselect = 40000

class ClickChart(object):

    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.fig=ax.figure
        self.ax = ax
        self.horiz_line = ax.axhline(y=ydataselect, color='black', linewidth=2)
        self.fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.onclick)

### Event handlers
    def onclick(self, event):
        self.horiz_line.remove()
        self.ypress = event.ydata
        self.horiz_line = ax.axhline(y=self.ypress, color='red', linewidth=2)
        txt.value = str(event.ydata)
        self.color_bar(event)

    def color_bar(self, event):

        for index, bar in enumerate(bars):
            bar.set_color(c=my_cmap(self.calc_prob(index)))
            print(index)

    def calc_prob(self, index):
        global mean, onesd_meanerror
        mean = mean.iloc[index]
        err = onesd_meanerror.iloc[index]
        result = norm.cdf(self.ypress, loc=mean, scale=err)
        return result

click = ClickChart(ax)```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close! The problem is you are re-defining `mean` inside of `calc_prob()`. Making changes to avoid this will fix the code and give the behavior you want:

```
def calc_prob(self, index):
    global mean, onesd_meanerror
    mean2 = mean.iloc[index] # Changed
    err = onesd_meanerror.iloc[index]
    result = norm.cdf(self.ypress, loc=mean2, scale=err) # Changed
    return result
```

[image: Dynamic figure]

Comment: Thank you! By far and away the best thing to happen to me today....spent a lot of time trying to work this out.  Much appreciated.